# Is silverlight and Java running on the web browser capable of saving "state" into the user's local machines?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, java, flash, plugins

I am aware that even after we have cleared our cache and cookies, websites can still save files/information into our computer using Flash (Flash *ever* cookies),

I was wondering does other plugins like Silverlight and Java have this problem?

Effectively, the question is:

When I use Incognito, what technologies will allow webpages to escape this incognito cage ?

Comment: If the provider could save the same state with a unique server side cookie would the be less of a concern?  I'm thinking about the high probability your browser is itself unique (https://panopticlick.eff.org/) or you have authenticated.

Comment: What security issue are you interested in: confidentiality (privacy), integrity (using state to exploit a vulnerability, or some other issue related to protecting some asset?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, depending on the browser and plugins used, there are many ways for a website to store persistent information on users' computer. It's not cookies and cache anymore. Some of these new methods require user confirmation, some don't - it also varies by browser. Flash has [Local Shared Objects](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), Silverlight has [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/), HTML5 itself gives [Offline Application](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/) cache, [Session Storage and Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).

It's not easy to clean them all at once. In fact, there is a proof-of-concept project that uses all those tricky ways and many others to create a super-persistent-and-resurecting-cookie - [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/). Of course, there is also an Evercookie killer called [Nevercookie](http://www.evercookiekiller.com/).

Comment: So who's the Nevercookie killer?

Comment: @Pacerier If only one client uses the same IP, you could use that to resurrect cookie. Of course, it isn't very efficient for Internet connexions with frequently changing IP.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. There are really many ways for a website to store persistent data on you, even if you dont want them too. [Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) by [Samy Kamkar](http://samy.pl/) is an example of this.

Quotede from the site of Evercookie it stores persistent data on you with the help of these storage mechanisms:

> - Standard HTTP Cookies
> - Local Shared Objects (Flash Cookies)
> - **Silverlight** Isolated Storage
> - Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached
> - PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
> - Storing cookies in Web History
> - Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
> - Storing cookies in Web cache
> - window.name caching
> - Internet Explorer userData storage
> - HTML5 Session Storage
> - HTML5 Local Storage
> - HTML5 Global Storage
> - HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite

Comment: But incognito will basically defeat everything other than the the 2nd and 3rd point right?

Comment: @Pacerier, Chromes incognito window defeats all the points in the list :)

Comment: What about Tor Browser?

Comment: @Pacerier, Tor Browser also safe. Once you restart it it does not manage to refind the evercookies.

Comment: are you familiar with Tor's "use new identity" functionality? Do I need to restart or is the `use new identity` sufficient?

Comment: Ahh. I believe you are referring to Vidala Control Panel's "use new identity". No this does not work. Only restart of Firefox will clear the evercookie.

Comment: @Pacerier "_Vidala Control Panel's "use new identity_" is only about **Tor exit point**. Tor does **not** know or care about HTTP cookies, HTTP ETags, HTML5 Session Storage, Flash super cookies...

Comment: @curiousguy could you elaborate the part on the `Tor exit point` ?

Comment: @Pacerier Tor is like the super-VPN (except it isn't a real VPN, Tor only gives you TCP and DNS, not IP access). Imagine you have an ISP that 1) will let you change your IP address as often as you like 2) won't ever reveal your true identity. That what's Tor tries to be (sort of - again, Tor does _not_ carry IP datagrams). Tor tries very hard to hide your the IP address your real ISP gave you. Nothing less, nothing more. If you have more questions about Tor, maybe you should ask a new question. (This comment box is tiny.)

Comment: (continued) When you browse a website through Tor, the source IP address the website sees is the Tor exit point your Tor client has chosen. Your Tor client can decide to use another exit point at any time. I'll add that it isn't easy for me to answer questions about Tor no knowing the level of your knowledge about Tor and your mental modem crowds systems.

Comment: @curiousguy ic, btw do you happen to work with / for Tor ?

Comment: @Pacerier I have installed and tried Tor, and support Tor goal, but that's it. I do not work for the development of Tor.

Answer (score 3):

Since 6u10 Java applets have been able to store "muffins" (effectively cookies) using [`java.jnlp.PersistenceService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html).

Also from the same release, Java applets can also open files through [`FileOpenService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileOpenService.html), [`FileSaveService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileSaveService.html) and [`ExtendedService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtendedService.html).

Comment: Are muffins built on top of cookies? In other words do muffins stay after I have cleared my cookies?

Comment: Muffins are an entirely separate bit similar mechanism. You don't even need a browser installed to use them with Java WebStart applications.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight can actually access the local filesystem, depending on the permissions granted. It is subject to .NET security mechanisms, but if these are badly configured, it is possible to read a user's files, or even change them.

Comment: holy, so basically if I surf with Silverlight enabled, just visiting a site could invite a virus in?

Comment: Yes, it could, but not just like that - you'd have to grant silverlight permission to write to 'interesting' locations, which it is not normally allowed to. The .NET security model is quite complicated, but it does make sense - silverlight plugins in the internet zone are mostly untrusted and will only be granted very limited access to system resources, so they can't just modify any registry key or dump dlls in windows\system32 or anything.

Comment: but they could install "programs" into my computer which if I unknowingly "run as administrator" that's all it takes to destroy my computer?